# strange Hive output

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here is the output from a Hive SQL query, wondering what means Map1 and Map3 here? And for Reducer 2, "2" means?

Here is the Hive SQL query and output,

```
select student_id, student_name
from
        (select student_id, student_name
        from students
        where grade='G1' and class in (3427, 34280)) T1
        inner join
        (select student_id from activities where is_active=true ) T2
        on T1.student_id=T2.student_id
limit 100;

Map 1: 21/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
Map 1: 22/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
Map 1: 23/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
Map 1: 25/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
Map 1: 26/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
Map 1: 27/359   Map 3: 1/1  Reducer 2: 0/59
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Please post your `Hivesql` as well. A wild guess, this is a multi-round map-reduce task.

Comment: What do you mean multi-round?

Comment: posted my hive sql, any advice is appreciated. :)